# Re-greasing Raleigh rea268

Tags: pedals

I have some pedals very similar to the one in the image.
It appears both sides have these seemingly non removable pins.

The round bit with the logo doesn't appear to be a dust cap. I already tried with a flat head screw driver and a hammer.

Is it not possible to regrease these pedals?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing these are not "serviceable".  At most you can trickle some oil in and let it sit threaded end up overnight, or work some grease into the bearing on the threaded end.  Someone who was really into hacks could cut through the rivets, disassemble, grease, then replace the rivets with long screws, but it would not really be worth the effort or expense.

Comment: oh they're rivets. I always thought rivets had a hole in the middle. Now I know.  I didn't think Raleigh would be stupid enough to make such garbage

Comment: Rivets, pins, whatever.  One end has a preformed head, and, after insertion in the pedal, the other end is peened over to make a head.  Saves probably 50 cents a pedal vs having threaded pins.